# Ejecutar clase o método al haber cambios en la base de datos

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Hola Quiero enviar un correo cuando hay algún cambio en una tabla en la base de datos, donde esta base de datos es externa y solo es de consulta, me podrían explicar como se realiza, me sirve también un método que se ejecute cada cierto tiempo.

Comment: Qué has intentado hasta ahora?

Comment: tengo la configuracion para enviar el correo en el settings.py con todo el mesaje y demas pero no se como hacer para que ese metodo se ejecute cuando hay un cambio en la base de datos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mira, puedes utilizar [Signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/signals/) de Django, son eventos que se ejecutan cuando pasa alguna acción y se pueden orientar al modelo y por ende en tu db, ahora, si quieres ejecutar alguna acción cuando pase algo en tu DB externo a Django te recomiendo que utilices un Trigger.

Comment: mira me explico mejor lo que quiro hacer en otra aplicación insertan los datos a la base de datos y esta aplicación se encarga de optener esa información insertada y enviarla a un correo para notificar que me sugieres, un tirigger tendria que ponerlo en la base de datos externa y no tengo permiso de editarla

Comment: aprendamos un poco jajaja, tienes una aplicación A que se encarga de insertar todos los datos a esta base de datos y luego tienes a la aplicación B que es quien los lee, esta aplicación B tiene que enviar un correo para notificar que se modifico o inserto algo, es así?, también dime, tu puedes modificar ambas aplicaciones?

Comment: si asi mismo , en la aplicacion A no puedo hacer nada porque no soy el propietario ni a la base de datos, solo puedo obtener información

Comment: que me sugieres que utilice Signals ?

Comment: No te va a funcionar por que es una ejecución a nivel código no DB, en este caso y lo único que se me ocurre es que hagas alguna tarea programada que verifique cada cierto tiempo si hay data nueva, para hacer esto puedes utilizar cron de linux, celery para django o lambda y cloudwatch de aws.

es lo único que se me ocurre.

Comment: Esta bien voy a ver cual me resuelve, me podrias ayudar también con esta pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/181686/conectar-base-de-datos-desde-la-vista  , pon el comentario último para marcarlo como respuesta